# Overlaying a Bitmap image with text and lines

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bitmap

I've got this big HeightMap TIFF image I need to show and process in my Windows form program.

I created two controls in my GUI, one of them is an OpenGL which generates a 3D scenario from the TIFF heightmap, and the other one is a pictureBox which shows the heightmap itself.

The problem is that I need to paint some lines and text over the image in the picture box.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288428/fastest-way-to-draw-an-overlay-on-an-image-in-windows-forms) how to effectively create a new image by combining two in an overlay fashion.

But I must not modify the image itself, otherwise the results in the 3D environment would be altered by these modifications. The image is huge (200MB) so cloning it and having two copies in memory would not be desirable.

Is there any way that I can over impose an image over another in the pictureBox, and only in the pictureBox, without altering the oiriginal?

I'm using Windows Forms with .NET Framework, programming language C#

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you draw that lines and text manually, or is it another picture, I didn't understand that part? Beacuse if you can, you can always set Image property (or something like that, didn't open VS in a long time) of pictureBox to contain your main image, and then draw onPaint event or overriding appropriate method, I think...

Comment: I must allow manually adding of those lines, it is not another picture. But if I "paint" over the image, I would be modifying the original picture, then altering the result in the OpenGL window (it is a heightmap, you take the color of each picture and assign a height by its value).

Comment: I don't see how you would be modifying original picture this way?

Comment: You're right, I thought drawing on the image using g.DrawImage(image2, new Point(0,0)) would inevitably modify the original image.

Guess I was wrong :)
Thanks!